# Can anyone point me towards a HiC Dataset with domains of high confidence?

Tags: hi-c, chromosome-capture, domains

is there a dataset online containing a HiC contact matrix and file with TAD boundary locations, which were generated, either by hand or automated, with high accuracy? Although I already used programs such as SpectralTAD or GMAP to generate TADs myself, a dataset which was computed with higher accuracy would be nice to check my project against.

Preferred attributes would be:

- human genome
- whole genome
- 10 kb resolution or higher

Thank you very much in advance!

edit: One dataset I found is http://chromosome.sdsc.edu/mouse/hi-c/download.html, which includes multiple 10 kb datasets with TADs called.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your best chance is one of the in-situ HiC papers from the Lieberman-Aiden lab. There are not too many HiC datasets with 10kb-or-better resolution out there for human. I would check this one:

[A 3D Map of the Human Genome at Kilobase Resolution Reveals Principles of Chromatin Looping](http://cell.com/fulltext/S0092-8674(14)01497-4)